# How do I fix this build error the on QuickDialog project?

Tags: objective-c, ios, quickdialog

I'm planning to use QuickDailog in my project, I cloned the project from github [here](https://github.com/escoz/quickdialog).

I'm trying to run the samples, but when I build the project I get following error

```
file:///QuickDialog/quickdialog/QuickDialogTableView.m: 
error: Semantic Issue: Second   argument to 'va_arg' is 
of non-POD type 'QElement *'
```

This is the code segment that is causing this error.

```
- (void)reloadCellForElements:(QElement *)firstElement, ... {
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, firstElement);
    NSMutableArray *indexes = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    QElement * element = firstElement;
    while (element != nil) {
        [indexes addObject:[self indexForElement:element]];

        //Below line generates the error
        element = va_arg(args, QElement *);
    }
    [self reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:indexes withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];

    va_end(args);
}
```

Any suggestions to fix the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How are you calling this method? What objects are you calling? Are you sending a null terminated list of objects?

I can't reproduce the issue, but googling around I found this:

http://builderror.com/article/47/Second-argument-to-vaarg-is-of-non-POD-type

Can you try to use that workaround and see if it solves the issue?

Comment: I haven't done any changes to the code, I just tried to build the project after downloading it from github. I'll try some workaround...

Comment: when exactly does this happen, when you compile it? Which compiler/xcode version are you using?

Comment: I have Xcode 4.2 Build:4D139 and using `Apple LLVM compiler 3.0` with ARC enabled

Comment: I use the latest version, Version 4.3.2 (4E2002), and it works fine on that. Maybe you can try upgrading it?

Comment: awesome, glad to hear that. Also, I just confirmed with somebody else that the tag 0.4 of the repository works on the previous version of Xcode.